# how to figure out a query's frequency?

Tags: mysql

how to calculate a query's frequency ? I doubt that some query is very often,I want to know its pqs,can any body tell me ? I have tried using general log,is there any tool to figure out ?

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Turn on the "general log" and use `pt-query-digest` to analyze the log.

Plan B:  Set `long_query_time = 0` and turn on the slowlog.  Then use `pt-query-digest` to analyze the log.

Caution:  In either case, disk will fill up fast.

With the slowlog you get a lot of other information -- useful if you are concerned about what is bogging down the system.  That is a different question than 'frequency'; it is frequency * avg execution time.